# Are there any computer vision chess programs which can be used for online games?

Tags: online-chess

I want to play online chess with a real chess board.  I learned that lichess can read the opponent's moves out loud, so I don't have to stare at the screen, which is a good start.  Now I need a way to send my moves to the PC.

I don't have a few hundred dollars laying around to buy a DGT board, but I do have a webcam, and I know that computer vision chess is a hot topic of research- I've seen many demonstrations on youtube.  Is this technology available yet for online play?

Comment: Why don't you just set up the board and move the pieces on the board and type it into the box on lichess? Your question is a little hard to understand.

Comment: I could also make the move on the virtual board if I wanted, but the goal is to use a real board to play online chess.  My question should be clear as I've indicated exactly what kind of tool I'm looking for.  If you don't understand my motivation that's fine, but my motivation is not essential to the question I'm asking.

Comment: on a side note, the lichess devs implmented a dgt board connect with lichess online server which is cool, https://lichess.org/dgt, Now they have not done any CV stuff on it, and a digital board will be required for relying the moves. How accurate do you think CV will be? Any chances of false positives.

Answer (score 3):

It seems this GitHub project provides what you're looking for:

"Program that enables you to play online chess using real chess board. Using computer vision it will detect the moves you make on chess board. After that, if it's your turn to move in the online game, it will make the necessary clicks to make the move."

https://github.com/karayaman/Play-online-chess-with-real-chess-board

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work for me... I'll keep following this project